# How to parallel a no data dependence for loop

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I am trying to parallel this for loop. I wasn't able to figure out how other people's answers substitute in the `$a` value and because my program depends on it.

Here is the original code I want to parallelize. cvp is an executable Cpp program. The purpose of this script is to loop from 0 to 29 using file_0 to file_29 with pc_0 to pc_29 and 0 to 29 as arguments and generate output file named from output_0 to output_29. Note that the program is also memory intensive, so if I can just parallel 4 (which is the amount of core i have ) that would be great.

```
#!/bin/bash
#testing script

for a in {0..29}
do
      set -x
      ./cvp -v -w 256 -F 16,0,0,0,0 -f 5 file_$a.gz >>output_$a pc_$a $a
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
parallel --results output_{} ./cvp -v -w 256 -F 16,0,0,0,0 -f 5 file_{}.gz pc_{} {} ::: {0..29}
```

or:

```
parallel ./cvp -v -w 256 -F 16,0,0,0,0 -f 5 file_{}.gz pc_{} {} ">>" output_{} ::: {0..29}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple palatalization with bash

You can create a function and pass variable `$a` as first parameter and run it in the background `&`, or you can just put a `&` at the end of your command in for loop, I prefer functions.

Function use the first parameter `$1` and do what you like each time it called.

`wait` will wait for all background process to completed, else the script can be completed before the background processes.

```
#!/bin/bash
#testing script

myfunction () {

./cvp -v -w 256 -F 16,0,0,0,0 -f 5 file_${1}.gz >>output_${1} pc_${1} ${1}

}


for a in {0..29}
do
        set -x
        myfunction ${a} &
done

wait
```

If you like to use gnu-parallel, I sure somebody will come up with a help as well. That give better control over palatalization, like that only run as many jobs as many cpu core you have. My example above not checking such things just launch them all.

So my example as it is, is not a good solution if you want to launch high amount of process at once.